# Lighting setup and light shaper tools to reproduce an image

Tags: lighting, technique

I was looking at Andrea Belluso website and liked many of his photos including this one:
[image]

http://belluso.format.com/fashion

Can you help deconstructing the photo so I can learn how he has done the lighting setup?
And here are the things I have:
Profoto B1 (two heads)
Profoto Wide zoom reflector
Profoto Zoom Reflector
Profoto Deep Umbrellas ( Silver, White, Translucent)
Profoto Octa soft box 2"
Profoto Beauty Dish White

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the shade from her hair and arm it looks like a single light was used. Looks like a beauty dish to me. 
I think I would go with just a single head in a Beauty Dish, with the dish being above and slightly left of the camera. I would angle it directly at her face, it seems that's where most of the light is going.